# Javascript, Safari/iPhone 5 no Number object

Tags: javascript, safari, iphone-5

I am using `Number(3000).toLocaleString('en')` in order to add comma's to numbers and format it properly. Seeing as this is a "core" JavaScript object I would definitely prefer it over any custom solution. However it does not work in mobile safari.

Anything that might fix that? Or will I just need to do a custom solution until safari is updated to add the functionality?

If I need anything custom is there a library that can fix this for browsers that do not support it?

Comment: toLocaleString always works, but it doesn't take an argument, and it's format is not specified; as long as SOMETHING shows up it "works" according to the spec. don't count on any one browser's formatting being representative of other browsers.,.

Comment: That does make sense. Just standard formatting not having a function is kind of unfortunate and coding something has so much room for error. I will start looking for a library anyway, so far only mobile safari has this problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Found a very easy to implement library for numbers, seems to work in all browsers with similar formatting to what I am currently using.

[Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)